# How to apply var height = $(window).height() - 20; to .followTo() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script. Its pretty simple. But my JS skills are shaky at best. It makes the navigation (which is positioned to the bottom of the window) scroll with the content until it reaches the top of the page then remains as fixed. Or as some would say "Sticky"

The issue im having is since my banner is 100% in height. The .followTo(830); only works on my screen resolution. How do I make followTo() find the windows current height  and then follow to that height and then subtract 20px from the followTo value? That would be ideal. Can this be accomplished fairly simply?

```
    var windw = this;
    $.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
        var $this = this,
            $window = $(windw);
        $window.scroll(function(e){
            if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: "20px"
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    bottom: '0',

                });
            }
        });
    };
    $('#mainNav').followTo(830);
```

*Someone said I need to use **`var height = $(window).height() - 20;`** but I am not sure how to apply it and they refused to elaborate instead just downvoting my posts and refering me to the entire jquery API.. Which isnt my learning style.*

Ive also attempted to use `if ($(document).height() - $window.height() - $('#mainNav').scrollTop() < pos)` I think im just messing up the syntax?

Comment: `var height = $(window).height() - 20; $('#mainNav').followTo(height);` Or if you wanted to use vanilla JS, you could set `height` to [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `var height = $(window).height() - 20;` in place of the 830 like this:

```
var height = $(window).height() - 20;
$('#mainNav').followTo(height);
```

Just keep in mind that the window size can change (for example the browser window gets resized or the device's orientation changes)

Comment: Thanks for the advice!! I fixed the (Browser window gets resized) issue by adding - ( $('#mainNav').innerHeight() + $('.globalHeader').innerHeight() )); instead of -20